# regular expression allows only decimal to enter

Tags: regex

```
^(0)?[0-9]{0,}((\.){1}[0-9]{0,2}){0,1}$
```

The above regular expression allows me to enter numbers upto 4 decimal places with an optional 0 before the decimal(.) point. But it is not throwing error when I'm not entering numbers  after decimal like 0., 12.,etc. !!!

Any  guidance on this.

Comment: What numbers do you want to match? Give some examples. Furthermore your regex allows up to 2 decimals.

Comment: that's correct...its 2 digits post decimal. 
Valid numbers: .23,12.23,12,12.2,etc.
Invalid numbers: 10.,12.326,etc
The reply by Sebastian has taken care of the problem. Many thanks @M42

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you allow between 0 and 2 digits after the `.`.

Since you said you wanted between 1 and 4 digits, you probably want this:

```
^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

Note, I have replaced `{0,}` with `*` and `{0,1}` with `?` as they are equivalent.

In addition, I've removed the `{1}`, as it matches one time per default.

The initial `(0)?` is also a bit redundant.

Beware, this regular expression matches `.50`. If you want to ensure that a number exists before the decimal point, change the first `*` to a `+` like so:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

To further simplify the regular expression, you can also replace `[0-9]` with `\d` in most regular expression engines, giving you:

```
^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Sebastian for the lucid explanantion. I used 
    ^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$ 
to achieve my ends

Comment: @Premanshu: Happy to help. Beware that if you want it to allow 12.3456, you will have to change the 2 to a 4.

Answer (score 2):

This regex could be simplified to the following:

```
^\d*(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2vamh